# View in MVC app takes very long time to populate ViewModel array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a controller - `TestController` - with an Index method. A view - `Index` -, and a ViewModel - `IndexViewModel`.

The `Index method` gets a list of an object - `TestObject` - from a database which is then passed to the ViewModel to be displayed in the `Index view`.

It takes about 500ms to obtain the list of TestObject, but when I try to display all of the items in the view, it takes upwards of 10-15 seconds. Which leads me to believe that if nothing is wrong with my LINQ query and backend, that the view rendering is what's holding it up.

Index Method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   List<TestObject> testObjects = _myRepository.GetTestObjects();
   return View(new IndexViewModel(_myRepository, testObjects));
}
```

IndexViewModel

```
public List<TestObject> TestObjects { get; set; }

public IndexViewModel() { }

public IndexViewModel(IMyRepository myRepository, List<TestObject>)
{
   TestObjects = testObjects;
}
```

Index View

```
<% if (Model.TestObjects != null && Model.TestObjects.Count() > 0) { %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TestObjectList", Model.TestObjects ); %>
<% }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try using Prefix to see if it can spot where your time is going, http://www.prefix.io/ .

Comment: What does the TestObjectList Partial look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot performance problems like this you can use something like [this](https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/AJAX/Dynatrace+AJAX+Edition+Community+Home), it breaks down very nicely why it takes so long to load, (look for we we still provide the old Dynatrace Ajax edition download) Its free and it looks great.

The other common problem I see is that the number of results you display on a page can vastly slow down or even crash the browser. How many rows or objects are you displaying?

What Browser are you using, does changing the browser change the performance?

Then you can look at any additional javascript, images  or css files you are sending, which can also slow down performance, aNd of course connection speed.